# How to Sign a Safe Transaction with an Other Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, smart-contract-wallets

I have a Safe "P" which is owned by another Safe "O". How do I send a transaction to Safe "O" with instructions to add my EOA as an owner to Safe "P" so I can manage it directly?